# Using custom datatypes in Entity POCOs?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1, poco

I have a business object, say a `User`.  A `User` has a `PhoneNumber` field, which is represented by a string.  I, for reasons best left to me, have created a `PhoneNumber` class that has implicit to/from string operators.  Do I have to do anything special to get the `PhoneNumber` written as a string to the database?  Right now, Entity has decided to break my `PhoneNumber` class up into its constituent parts (`AreaCode`, `Prefix`, etc) and save those to the database individually.  `PhoneNumber` is stored in a separate assembly.

```
public class PhoneNumber : IEquatable<PhoneNumber>, IComparable<PhoneNumber>
{
    public static implicit operator string (PhoneNumber ph)
    {
        return ph.ToString ();
    }

    public static implicit operator PhoneNumber (string number)
    {
        return Parse(number);
    }

    public static PhoneNumber Parse(string number)
    {
       // ...
    }

    public override string ToString ()
    {
        // produce a Parse-compatible output
    }
}

public class User
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
    public virtual PhoneNumber Phone { get; set; }
}

public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Entityframework is working correctly taking your entity class and representing each of the Properties as columns. Is your PhoneNumber class a partial, if so you can override your ToString() in the none generated partial of the PhoneNumber class. That way it doesn't matter how it's stored in the database the object can give you that information.

Comment: It's not a partial class, but the object does override ToString() and produce the result I expect.  I'll update with some sample code.

Comment: Ok so I guess the question is then, why do you want the phonenumber stored as a string instead of the entity representation. EF is always going to take property to column or column to property depending on if you are doing code first or not.

Comment: It's just awkward in the database to have 5 columns devoted to storing chunks of the phone number, instead of a canonical "(101) 555-1234" representation.  Maybe it's not a big deal?

Comment: What is awkward about it?  Having 3 separate fields will enforce the format and allow each application to display the fields internally in any format they want.  Otherwise, you will need to worry about 101.555.1234 vs 101-555-1234 vs (101) 555-1234 vs 1015551234.  Using one column, how would you query for all records for a given area code, exchange, country code, etc.  All of these queries are much easier to write if you store it in parts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way is a workaround like this:

```
// You want to store in same table and not a navigation property, right?
// Then you need [ComplexType]
[ComplexType] 
public class PhoneNumber : IEquatable<PhoneNumber>, IComparable<PhoneNumber>
{
    // ...

    public string FullNumber
    {
        get
        {
            return Prefix + "-" + AreaCode + " " + Number; // or whatever
        }
        set
        {
            AreaCode = ParseToAreaCode(value); // or so...
            Prefix = ParseToPrefix(value);     // or so...
            Number = ParseToNumber(value);     // or so...
        }
    }

    [NotMapped]
    public string AreaCode { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public string Prefix { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public string Number { get; set; }
}
```

This way you would get only a `FullNumber` column in the database.

Comment: This is what I needed, and actually let me add a packed format for phone number.  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

If the rest of your design allows it, you could leave the `PhoneNumber` class out of the mapping and let `User` handle a string representation of it, like:

```
public class User
{
  public virtual int Id { get; set; }
  public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }

  public virtual string PhoneNumber
  { 
      get { return this.PhoneNumber.ToString(); } // TODO: check for null
      set { this.PhoneNumber = PhoneNumber.Parse(value); }
  }

  [NotMapped]
  public virtual PhoneNumber Phone { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This is an equally viable solution.  I'm going with Slauma's because I want the PhoneNumber itself to be more reusable, but there are plenty of cases where this pattern would work for me.